# throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event . Loading images from MongoDB with a promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am trying to load in data from MongoDB. I am very to new to "Promises". I am getting a "throw er; //Unhandled 'error event" exception thrown. What is wrong with my code? Is the promise handled correctly?

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1300:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1348:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1436:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/alexbrito/Documents/VisualStudioCode/theSkyDoesNotExist/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexbrito/Documents/VisualStudioCode/theSkyDoesNotExist/server.js:40:5)
```

Images.controller.js

```
 const IMAGE_MODEL = require('./../model/Images.model');
    const MongoDatabase = require('./../MongoDatabase');

    let pathToImages = [];

    function getImages() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (MongoDatabase.openConnection) {
          resolve('Images inserted in array');
        } else {
          reject('Images were not inserted');
        }
      });
    }

    getImages()
      .then(fromResolve => {
        IMAGE_MODEL.find({}).exec((error, images) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log();
          } else {
            images.forEach(x => {
              pathToImages.push(x.path);
            });
            console.log(pathToImages);
            console.log(fromResolve);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(fromReject => {
        console.log(fromReject);
      });



   module.exports.getImages = getImages;
```

Comment: `kill 4000`  it may help

Comment: Do I run ^C ? @kedarsedai

Comment: or this there another way to kill the server @kedarsedai

Comment: Ctrl c stops the server but if you run again your application it will run on tbe same `port`

Comment: How do I kill 4000 then? @kedarsedai

Comment: Is the promise set up correctly ? @kedarsedai

Comment: `lsof -i TCP:4000 | grep LISTEN` type this in your command and say what does it return ?

Comment: node    51179 alexbrito   24u  IPv6 0xefd3a523ec103fcd      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN) @kedarsedai

Comment: `kill -9 51179`  type this

Comment: I am still getting the exception. I run "npm run dev". When I save my Images.controller.js thats when it throws the exception @kedarsedai

Comment: "node    51330 alexbrito   24u  IPv6 0xefd3a523ec10028d      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)" I ran that line you provided. => [ kill -9 51330 ] Let me try again. I will save server.js then Images.controller.js @kedarsedai

Comment: Does it work or same issues?

Comment: Same issues @kedarsedai .

Comment: which `os` are you using `windows` or `Linux`?

Comment: Linux @kedarsedai

Comment: `sudo pkill node` try this

Comment: Ahhh sorry man. I actually have Unix @kedarsedai

Comment: I still ran that line. Linux and Unix are alike I figured I'd try. Its behaving a bit better now. @kedarsedai

Comment: okay !! let me know if you were done